# How to avoid this bogus "dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter" warning?

Tags: php

On PHP V5.6.13,

```
dirname("",1);
```

gives

```
Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given
```

despite http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

```
string dirname ( string $path [, int $levels = 1 ] )
```

How can I avoid this bogus warning appearing?

Comment: Second parameter will be added in PHP 7 (Read the changelog: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php#refsect1-function.dirname-changelog) and `PHP 5.6 !== PHP 7`

Comment: You can safely drop `1` as a second param; it will be ignored on PHP 5.x, and it will be filled by default with `1` anyway on PHP 7.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upgrade to PHP 7.

> #### Changelog
>
> ```
> Version   Description  
> 7.0.0     Added the optional levels parameter.
> ```

Comment: Well if he uses the code in production, I wouldn't recommend to upgrade to PHP 7.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend upgrading either, but it will get the warning to disappear.

Comment: Thanks. Extremely poor docs here, showing the V7 version for V5.

Comment: @ChrisJJ not poor, just trying to be as up to date as possible (we don't have separate docs for each version)… that's what the changelog is for then ;-)

Comment: @bwoebi "not poor, just trying to be as up to date as possible" What's poor is that they are not as accurate as they could be. Up-to-date is no excuse for being inaccurate for previous versions.

Comment: @ChrisJJ They're open source, if you see an issue, feel free to suggest an edit :)

Comment: My Live is in php5 If I change it to php7 then all of my site shows problem for changing this. So that reason how to change it for php5 @Ignnacio Vazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have PHP 7, use the function below to have a recursive dirname with levels:

```
function dirname_r($path, $count=1){
    if ($count > 1){
       return dirname(dirname_r($path, --$count));
    }else{
       return dirname($path);
    }
}
echo dirname_r(__FILE__, 2);
```

Comment: Not Forgotten $this->dirname_r();